# Stopping 2nd webrtc stream in Chrome breaks all webrtc streams

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

If I open two separate WebRTC local video streams in Chrome 55, and I stop and start the second stream three times, the first stream breaks (and no more streams can be opened after this point).

https://jsfiddle.net/kqjmt7a0/1/

To repro easily, run the fiddle above in Chrome 55 and click "Restart vid2" three times. The third time you click it, you'll notice that:

- The first video frame (which is not touched by the click!) freezes
- The second video frame no longer plays
- There are no errors (getUserMedia() returns a new local stream that *looks* fine except that it doesn't work)

Specifically, it is the call to MediaStreamTrack::stop() that is messing up Chrome (eventually). Commenting out the following fixes the problem:

```
  var tracks = stream.getTracks();
  for(var i = 0; i < tracks.length; ++i) {
    tracks[i].stop();
  }
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here or is this simply a Chrome bug?

Notes:

- This just to work just fine in Chrome
- This works just fine in Firefox
- Repro-ed in Chrome 55.0.2883.87 (both Mac and Windows)

**Update:**

After playing around with this further I am more convinced that it is simply a Chrome bug. I have entered the following:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=674965

I would still appreciate feedback as to whether there's anything wrong with my code that might be tickling the bug.

Comment: videl.src = '' after track.stop()
tentatively, the problem does not happen

Comment: I confirm that changing the order of cleanup as you describe avoids the bug. Thanks! Still doesn't explain anything, but it appears to be a workaround.

Comment: you might want to use .srcObject = stream instead of URL.createObjectURL. You should also try revoking the object URL.

(createObjectURL is known to be cause issues with dangling object references... this looks like it)

Comment: @PhilippHancke Unfortunately it seems that using srcObject does not fix the issue. I'm still able to repro. Thanks for the suggestion though.

PS: can you provide reference for leaky createObjectURL?

Comment: Voting to close as no longer able to reproduce, since it was filed as a chrome bug and later marked as resolved.